# How to add icon on Customize Toolbar?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I am trying to add a button on the Customize Tool Window on **Firefox 4**

My folders look like this:

```
addon
 |- content
    |- om
       |- xul
          |- browser.xul
          |- browser.css
 |- skin
    |- default
       |- icon.png
```

My `chrome.manifest` file:

```
content orkutmanager content/om/
content orkutmanager content/om/ contentaccessible=yes

skin    orkutmanager default skin/default/

locale  orkutmanager en-US locale/en-US/

overlay chrome://global/content/browser.xul chrome://orkutmanager/content/xul/browser.xul
```

My `browser.xul` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="chrome://orkutmanager/content/xul/browser.css"?>

<overlay xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

    <toolbarpalette id="BrowserToolbarPalette">
        <toolbarbutton id="orkutmanager-button" label="OM"
                       class="toolbarbutton-1 chromeclass-toolbar-additional"
                       tooltiptext="Orkut Manager"/>
    </toolbarpalette>

</overlay>
```

Accessing `chrome://orkutmanager/content/xul/browser.xul` gets me to a blank page, which means the file was found. (Should something be rendered?).

Accessing `chrome://global/content/browser.xul` gets me to an error page:

```
Firefox can't find the file at jar:file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Mozilla Firefox 4.0 Beta 7/omni.jar!/chrome/toolkit/content/global/browser.xul
```

Isn't this file supposed to exist? Did it move? How can I add an icon on the Customize Toolbar window?

Comment: DId you see this? http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=934345

Comment: @drachen that is not really related. The file was not found because it was probably moved. If it couldn't load `browser.xul` my Firefox would be a total mess, probably wouldn't startup. I am missing something here...

Comment: @drachenstern thanks for the help. You made me find the problem :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I should post this as an answer for accepting:

---

http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=934345

seems to demonstrate roughly the problem you are looking at. However, you commented that this was not correct entirely, but that it did lead to you finding the problem which was the inclusion of the filename in a different place.

For others fighting the same problem, ensure that all the new paths are up to date.

Thanks.

Comment: And as @MatrixFrog have suggested, I add some stuff here as well https://developer.mozilla.org/en/creating_toolbar_buttons

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `chrome://global/content/browser.xul` it is `chrome://browser/content/browser.xul`.

[I found a page, here,](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/creating_toolbar_buttons) where it is explains very well how to achieve this.

[In another documentation page,](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_School/Adding_Toolbars_and_Toolbar_Buttons) I found:

> The CSS file with your toolbar styles
>   needs to be included in the overlay
>   file, as you would expect, but also in
>   the chrome.manifest file. This is very
>   important because the toolbar
>   customization dialog won't work
>   correctly without this. The way to
>   include the file in the manifest is to
>   add this line:

```
style chrome://global/content/customizeToolbar.xul chrome://xulschoolhello/skin/toolbar.css
```

<sub>The documentation is very messy, I was looking at one about Firefox 1.5 when I copied the url. :S</sub>

Comment: Keep in mind that MDC is a wiki, so if the documentation is messy, you can help fix it. Even if you just add or remove a few words to make it clearer, it will bring it that much closer to being nice, readable documentation.